# Having trouble rendering grid in a template

Tags: umbraco

I'm in the process of using the grid datatype with a custom editor and I'm having trouble rendering the data on a template.

I don't believe the custom editor is causing any problem as that seems to be working correctly and storing the data.

I have a feeling it may be because of the way I have my page set up:

Essentially I have a parent page, with nested 'content region' document types beneath it. These 'content regions' have a property that uses the grid data type.

On my page template I'm trying to iterate over all the nested content regions, and render the grid data for each.

So on my page template I have this:

```
<body>
....
@Html.Partial("About/ContentRegions")
....
</body>
```

And then within my partial I have the following:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage

@foreach (var contentRegion in Model.Content.Children.Where(cr => cr.IsVisible()))
{
    <div class="page-content-wrap">
        <div class="text-content" id="@(contentRegion.Name.ToLower().Replace(" ", ""))">
            <!-- Main Heading -->
            <h1>@(contentRegion.GetPropertyValue<string>("mainHeading"))</h1>

            <!-- Sub Heading -->
            <h3>@(contentRegion.GetPropertyValue<string>("introduction"))</h3>
            <div class="underline"></div>

            @Html.GetGridHtml(contentRegion, "regionBodyText");

        </div>
        <div class="text-separator">
            <!-- Separator -->
            <hr>
            <!-- Separator -->
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Hopefully this all makes sense so far and you can see I'm simply trying to render the grid data for each of my nested content regions. However when I try to view the page I receive the following error:

[image]

When I edit the 'Bootstrap3.cshtml' view and simply spit out the model, it seems to display the json string with all of the content for the grid editor ie:

[image]

So from what I can gather, it seems the json isn't being deserialized properly for the bootstrap3 view to handle the data. It's simply treating it as a string which is why it's throwing the error.

I don't know exactly what I've done wrong here but I have a feeling it's something to do with me having this 'content region' nested children set up. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using your own grid template? The umbraco guys implemented the template with dynamics thats why you get this error. The header off the template should look something like this:

```
@inherits UmbracoViewPage<dynamic>
@using Umbraco.Web.Templates
@using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
```

You could use [GridData](https://github.com/skybrud/Skybrud.Umbraco.GridData) to get the grid as typed model.

Hope this helps.